# Struct array inside another struct in golang

Tags: arrays, go, struct

I am new to `golang` and trying to create `json` in this format using `golang`

```
{
    "Title": "You are awesome",
    "Url": "www.youareawesome.com",
    "Desc": "your awesome desc is here",
    "Payment": {
        "Discount": "15%",
        "outlets": [
            {
                "Location": "nowhere"
            },
            {
                "Location": "everywhere"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

below is my code for `struct`

```
type Partner struct {
    Title   string `json:"Title"`
    URL     string `json:"Url"`
    Desc    string `json:"Desc"`
    Payment Payment `json:"Payment"`
}

type Payment struct {
    Discount string `json:"Discount"`
    outletList [] OutletItem `json:"outletList"`
} 

type OutletItem struct {
    Location string `json:"Location"`
}
```

this is how i am doing

```
partner := Partner{} 
payment := Payment{}
partner.Title = "You are awesome"
partner.Desc = "your awesome desc is here"
payment.Discount = "15%"
payment.AddOutletItem(OutletItem{Location:"nowhere"})
partner.Payment = payment
partner.Url = "www.youareawesome.com"
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(partner)


func (payment *Payment) AddOutletItem(item OutletItem) []OutletItem {
    payment.outletList = append(payment.outletList, item)
    return payment.outletList
}
```

I am unable to see the outlet array in the payment object i am not sure if i have missed out any thing.

Answer (score 4):

`OutletList` must be uppercase if you want to export this field

```
type Payment struct {
    Discount   string        `json:"Discount"`
    OutletList [] OutletItem `json:"outletList"`
}
```

Comment: Great, that was the issue.
Thanks